# what does it mean to define a reference as another reference

Tags: c++, reference

See below:

```
  int n = 0;
  int &p = n;  
  int &k = p;
  k = 99;
```

The changes in `k` also affect value of `n`. What's the principle behind `int &k = p;` I'd like to know how is it differ from `int k = p;`. I know the result of `k`, but i want to know how the compiler to behind that.

Comment: Does that code even compile?

Comment: yes , it does comple. I'm using VS2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at references as some kind of alias. The variable `p` is an alias for `n`, whenever you use `p` you actually use `n`. This means that `k` *also* becomes an alias for `n`.

Comment: can you explain it from the compiler level?

Comment: @henryyao: Are you asking "can you explain how compilers implement references and parse C++ code?" Because that's _way_ out of the scope of a Stack Overflow question ... and certainly of a comment. Have you ever taken a three-year course on compilers? That'd be a good start. Then get to know the C++ toolchains. You should have a decent understanding of them within ten years or so. Why do you want to know? C++ is an _abstraction_. You're not supposed to give a flying f### about "the compiler level".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I agree that *"can you explain how compilers implement references [in general] and parse C++ code?"* would be off topic for SO, but the question of how a compiler handles that particular situation is really not that complicated (as JSF demonstrated)

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic strategies for the compiler, but it is not limited to these two (whatever achieves the desired semantics might be used):

1) In your example, the compiler can see the scope of `n` in relation to the scope of `p` and `k`, so it simply knows at compile time that `p` and `k` are aliases for `n` and every time you reference `p` or `k` it generates the same code as if you had referenced `n`.  That is a less common, but still important usage pattern for references.

2) In harder (for the compiler) situations, the reference variable is actually implemented as a pointer.  So when you say `int &p=n;` the compiler effectively substitutes `int *hidden_p = &n;`  Then later when you say `p` the compiler effectively substitutes `(*hidden_p)`  So when you say `int &k=p;` that means `int &k=(*hidden_p);` which means `int *hidden_k=&(*hidden_p);` which effectively means `int *hidden_k=hidden_p;`